# Choosing between institutes amid a pandemic

Tags: graduate-admissions, masters, india, covid-19

I have been offered an admit at a institute closer to my house. I also have the option to upgrade to a slightly better institute which is more than 1000 miles away from my home. Although classes will be conducted online, as new attendees we'll have to go through a document verification phase before the admission. Institutes haven't notify anything about this phase whether it will be conducted online or offline. And thus I am stuck in a dilemma. I have to choose between  a good enough institute which is safer to travel to amidst a pandemic and a slightly better institute which involves lot of risk to travel to.

If the institutes would have made clear that physical appearance of a candidate isn't necessary for document verification I would have chosen the better institute.

Should I trust the institute that they would definitely make safe choices for candidates or make a safe choices for myself and go with the inferior institute.

The institutes I'm talking about are big name IITs and I have been offered a two years Masters course.

Comment: The other institute is 1000 miles away. If you choose to go there, do you plan to take the train? Are trains in India still crowded as usual? If it is still crowded, my advice would be not to go there.

Comment: Yes, I plan to take the train. I don't think trains are crowded anymore because of the pandemic situation and the measures the railway have taken.

Comment: Unfortunately, we really can't predict what a particular institute's document verification process is likely to entail, and only you can determine the level of risk you are willing to accept. Personally, I would attend the institute I thought was a better academic match.

Comment: @sbhhdp I expect the joining process,in the IITs, would be made flexible considering the special situation regarding COVID. But it's always better to make sure. Consider sending them a mail asking clarification on this. Their mail ids can be found on their websites usually.

Answer (score 1):

If you were, e.g., based in New Zealand (which has done superbly with Covid-19) and were thinking of attending a New Zealand university versus attending an Indian university, then it would be different. You could reasonably say that choosing the New Zealand university would keep you safe from Covid, but going to India puts you at risk. But since you're already in India, the "extra" risk is based solely on the travel you have to do to get to the other institution. That should only be a day or so, a much shorter time than the actual study time you'll have to do at both institutions. Therefore it seems sensible to base the decision on whether you can protect yourself while studying at both institutions, not on the travel.

That said, moving to a foreign city is always going to be difficult since you'll have to do things like find a place to stay, places to buy food, a place to wash clothes, and so on.

Ultimately it's a decision you'll have to make for yourself. The circumstances are uncertain, meaning there's no clear-cut best option. Choose whatever feels right, and it'll be the correct choice.